# Antd Table Search and Reset functions not functioning

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, antd

I am trying to implement search and reset functions in Antd table. The reset(clearAll) function is not returning the table back to its initial state when clicked. The search code blocks logs these errors on the console === >

```
     TS2322: Type 'any[]' is not assignable to type 'undefined'.
     280 |   };
     281 |   const globalSearch = () => {
   > 282 |     filteredValue = modifiedData.filter(value => {
    |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
     283 |       return (
     284 |         value.name.toLowerCase().includes(searchText.toLowerCase()) ||
```

And

```
    TS2339: Property 'length' does not exist on type 'never'.
     319 |             }}
     320 |             columns={mergedColumns}
   > 321 |             dataSource={filteredValue && filteredValue.length ? filteredValue : 
     modifiedData}
    |                                                        ^^^^^^
```

These are the codes

```
     const [sortedInfo, setSortedInfo] = useState({});  
     const [searchText, setSearchText] = useState('');
     let [filteredValue] = useState();
```

Code block for resetting the table

```
const clearAll = () => {
setSortedInfo({});       ===> coming from the sorted Values
setSearchText('');
loadData();           ====> Data from the API loads when useEffect is called
};
```

Code block for Search

```
      const handleSearch = e => {
      setSearchText(e.target.value);
      if (e.target.value === '') {
       loadData();
      }
     };
     const globalSearch = () => {
     filteredValue = modifiedData.filter(value => {
      return (
      value.name.toLowerCase().includes(searchText.toLowerCase()) ||
      value.tankThreatLevelColor.toLowerCase().includes(searchText.toLowerCase())
     );
      });
     setGridData(filteredValue);
    };
```

In the jsx

```
      <Space style={{ marginBottom: 16 }}>
      <Input placeholder="Enter Search Text" onChange={handleSearch} type="text" allowClear 
       value={searchText} />
      <Button type="primary" onClick={globalSearch}>
        Search
      </Button>
      <Button onClick={clearAll}>Reset Table</Button>
      </Space>

        <Table
        components={{
          body: {
            cell: EditableCell,
          },
        }}
        columns={mergedColumns}
        dataSource={filteredValue && filteredValue.length ? filteredValue : modifiedData}
        bordered
        
      />
```

Much Gratitude in anticipation

Comment: Can you provide codesandbox or StackBlitz link for your issue if possible? Thank you :)

Comment: Thanks for your response. This is the link https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-tle83i?file=Hello.tsx

Answer (score 0):

Update your `globalSearch()` with following code.

replace

`value.tankThreatLevelColor.toLowerCase().includes(searchText.toLowerCase())`

with

`value.username.toLowerCase().includes(searchText.toLowerCase())`

as there is no column with name `tankThreatLevelColor`

[image: Error screenshot]

Update your `globalSearch()` with following code.

```
const globalSearch = () => {
    filteredValue = modifiedData.filter((value) => {
    return (
      value.name.toLowerCase().includes(searchText.toLowerCase()) ||
      value.username.toLowerCase().includes(searchText.toLowerCase())
    );
  });
    setGridData(filteredValue);
 };
```

Search by name result:

[image: Screenshot]

Search by username result:

[image: Screenshot]

After reset:
[image: Screenshot]

Comment: I am sorry I didn't explain to you. I used json mock data as my API so that's where the value "username "is coming from. Its still the same with my initial codes just a change in values

Comment: @Joca do you still get the same error on Stackbliz code link which you shared?

Comment: I get this error Cannot read properties of null (reading 'toLowerCase'), when I click on the search button after search values have been inputted.